# SMD package size chart

Tags: surface-mount

Is there a scale drawing of SMD package sizes as a design aid? This could be useful in schematic/layout stages of a project in when deciding to trade off size vs. cost.

Comment: Below answer is how I'd normally do it just be dropping onto a PCB layout, but I found a chart at http://chibi-sakura.org/images/smd_chart_v01.png that may be useful although it doesn't cover a great range of footprints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TI has a nice [pdf chart](http://www.ti.com/lit/sl/sszb138a/sszb138a.pdf) for their ic packages, at actual size. Organized by pin count and package type. This is Texas Instruments centered, but the information translates well between manufacturers.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20171118032809/https%3A//www.ti.com/lit/sl/sszb138a/sszb138a.pdf  Also https://e2echina.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/00-60-00-00-00-00-18-30/TI_6C51F853AF824772015CC5884B628C51_.pdf

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, a printer is the most useful design aid / sanity check. For example, I use Eagle to design my PCBs, and there are reference packages available for a very large range of devices. Simply printing out the design 1:1 helps a lot. It can also help you see things like "Those parts look like they would be hard to solder/probe" and "These parts are too close/far away". It's also cheap and fast. Some manufacturers will put 1:1 footprint drawings in datasheets as well, and you can use those for reference.

As for a *specific* design aid, I also have the [SparkFun Reference Board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8754?), which helps you see what holes, text, and common packages look like on a footprint. I find it useful at times, especially when I'm trying to figure out readability of text.

Comment: If you have time, order the parts before laying out the board.  This will show you something about part availability.  And you can see the physical part sitting on a 1:1 printout.  It's surprising how sizes all look the same in the CAD program.

Comment: @markrages Absolutely, I recommend the same. It's also a great way to catch any pin pitch, width, and size mismatch between your footprint and the actual part.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but to add to the knowledge base (for those who google it around like me) I found the following link for SMD standard size chart

https://github.com/hemalchevli/Open-Source-PCB-Ruler

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It would be best to edit a picture or two into the answer in case the repository ever goes away.